# Selecting from two tables, with different columns, where one needs a count

Tags: mysql, select, count, where-clause

I have two tables, TableA and TableB.
I need to select one count value from TableA, based on a where condition.
I need to select two values from TableB.
I'd like all the values in one result set.  There will never be more than one row in the result set.

Here's what I have now:

`SELECT count(id) FROM TableA WHERE ($some_where_statement) SELECT owner, owner_ID from TableB`

I know this should be simple, but this is throwing an error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're looking for. Could you include some sample data and what you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 1):

You can cross join to join rows from two unrelated tables:

```
SELECT T1.cnt, T2.owner, T2.owner_ID
FROM (SELECT count(id) FROM TableA WHERE ($some_where_statement)) AS T1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT owner, owner_ID from TableB) AS T2
```

To have only one row in the result set, it is assumed that both subqueries only return one row. I suspect that this is not the case for the second subquery. You are probably missing a where clause.